# Image is not rendering as text, when I bind it with angular js model in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've created one jsfiddle for the same [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9bU5/74/)

sample HTML code

```
<div ng-app="myAppModule" ng-controller="someController">
<!-- Show the name in the browser -->
<!-- Bind the input to the name -->
<span ng-bind="showImage"></span>
</div>
<script>

</script>
```

sample angular js code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myAppModule', []);
myApp.controller('someController', function($scope) {
// do some stuff here
$scope.showImage="<a class='fancybox' href='http://i.imgur.com/9VFmFrN.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' title='Personalized Title'><img class='MaxUploadedSmallSized' src='http://i.imgur.com/9VFmFrNs.jpg' alt=''></a>";
```

I'm trying to render image from angular js model on front end UI but it is coming as text.

I've tried $compile property of angular js too but that is not working too.

snapshot

[image]

Comment: You should not do it like this. HTML must be in HTML, not in JS.

Comment: then what is the correct approach ?

Comment: If you want to show/hide something, put it in HTML and use `ngShow/ngHide` directives. You don't want to pollute JS with representation.

Comment: and if you want to load template use `ng-include`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data structure to your controller that contains the relevant informations:

```
$scope.showImage=[];
$scope.showImage.Link='http://i.imgur.com/9VFmFrN.jpg';
$scope.showImage.Source='http://i.imgur.com/9VFmFrN.jpg';     
$scope.showImage.Title='Personalized Title';
```

The access it in your html as if you are using a template engine:

```
<div>
  <a class='fancybox' ng-href='{{showImage.Link}}' data-fancybox-group='gallery' title='{{showImage.Title}}'><img class='MaxUploadedSmallSized' ng-src='{{showImage.Source}}' alt=''></a>
</div>
```

Look here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2t8p9wx/1/)